# Lenovo ideapad can't scan for wifi signal after Ubuntu installation

Tags: wireless, lenovo, realtek, scanner

I am a newbie at Ubuntu and have reached my limit trying to get my laptop which has no ethernet port to connect.

`$ sudo lshw -enable TEST`

```
stacy-computer            
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3830MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 929MHz
          capacity: 2700MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=ivb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:e0000000-e03fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:2000(size=64)
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:cfa08000-cfa0ffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:26 memory:e0400000-e040ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-21-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-21-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: Cruzer Glide
                   vendor: SanDisk
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@3:2
                   logical name: scsi6
                   version: 1.27
                   serial: 20051738030CB2F0286B
                   capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-disk
                      description: SCSI Disk
                      product: Cruzer Glide
                      vendor: SanDisk
                      physical id: 0.0.0
                      bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
                      logical name: /dev/sdb
                      version: 1.27
                      serial: 20051738030CB2F0286B
                      size: 14GiB (15GB)
                      capabilities: removable
                      configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                    *-medium
                         physical id: 0
                         logical name: /dev/sdb
                         size: 14GiB (15GB)
                         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                       *-volume
                            description: Windows FAT volume
                            vendor: MSDOS5.0
                            physical id: 1
                            logical name: /dev/sdb1
                            logical name: /media/soulfire76/DA6E-CA8A
                            version: FAT32
                            serial: da6e-ca8a
                            size: 14GiB
                            capacity: 14GiB
                            capabilities: primary fat initialized
                            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:e041c000-e041c00f
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:e0421000-e04213ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-21-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: USB2.0-CRW
                      vendor: Generic
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@1:1.3
                      version: 39.60
                      serial: 20100201396000000
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
                      vendor: Realtek
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:1.4
                      version: 2.00
                      serial: 00e04c000001
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 bluetooth
                      configuration: driver=rtl8xxxu maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:2
                      description: Human interface device
                      product: Touchscreen
                      vendor: ELAN
                      physical id: 5
                      bus info: usb@1:1.5
                      version: 80.13
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:30 memory:e0418000-e041bfff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:e0420000-e04203ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-21-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Human interface device
                      product: Lenovo Yoga
                      vendor: Invensense
                      physical id: 5
                      bus info: usb@2:1.5
                      version: 11.41
                      serial: B62B746F2D000A00
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Video
                      product: Lenovo EasyCamera
                      vendor: Sunplus IT Co
                      physical id: 7
                      bus info: usb@2:1.7
                      version: 50.28
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:27 ioport:2088(size=8) ioport:2094(size=4) ioport:2080(size=8) ioport:2090(size=4) ioport:2060(size=32) memory:e041f000-e041f7ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:e041d000-e041d0ff ioport:2040(size=32)
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:e041e000-e041efff
     *-scsi
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SAMSUNG MZMTD128
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 2L0Q
             serial: S15FNEAD200893
             size: 119GiB (128GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=5d0f32fb-b4ba-479f-b9b9-ccf89064a783 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 51a5-aa52
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 0f2ee6d4-750a-43d0-97a5-7e2ad7e8a2e3
                size: 114GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2016-07-11 14:27:38 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-07-11 17:30:26 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2016-07-11 17:30:27 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 1
                serial: 93563bfc-ca2f-4299-a20d-7e0a640b6f69
                size: 3974MiB
                capacity: 3974MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.4
       logical name: wlx24fd520db363
       serial: 24:fd:52:0d:b3:63
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Well, I rebooted and all was well. There's power in asking a question, I guess. Thanks anyway.